# Select html field is different on IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-select, internet-explorer-11

I noticed that in IE 11, select fields (dropdowns) have a diffent appearance (and the other form fields looks different as well). It looks flat on IE 11 while on other browsers (even lower IE browsers), it is not.

Is this an effect of Window's Metro UI which is only available on Windows 8? If it is then why am I experiencing it on Windows 7?

Is there a way to force form fields to use older ui? I've used `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >` but it does not work.

Please refer to this link for a live sample. Use IE 11 please.

http://jsfiddle.net/u8xtumya/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it looks flat" but all browsers style the native `<select>` element slightly different in their own way. Personally I like the IE 11 one but I find the opening animation a bit slow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @rink.attendant.6. What I mean of "it looks flat" is it looks windows 8 to me. The narrow edges, plain color, just like the new look of developer tool of IE11.Well it also looks good to me but our team targets that our project behaves as same as possible to all major browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the way `select` are being styled by IE11. This might or might not be directly related to the Metro UI, but that doesn't matter.

Setting an older compatibility mode will not affect the looks of elements. It will make sure you miss out on functionality that has been added to IE11 that was not present in older versions. It's a bad idea to use anything but the latest compatibility mode if there's not a very good reason to do so (like your web app is old and doesn't run in the latest version).

You can use CSS to style the `select` (and the `::-ms-expand` pseudo-class to style the arrow that expands the menu)